# Microsoft-provided data provider classes, the good and the bad?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

What are advantages and disadvantages of Microsoft-provided data provider classes in ADO.NET? are they fast?

Comment: Johnny, you do know that the _provider classes_ are just the data-access layers (drivers) don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLServer.NET data provider is high-speed and robust, but requires SQL Server license purchased from Microsoft, or you can get a free Express Version (if you get the new SQL Server R2 Express you get 10 GB of database storage!) (thanks from the comments, slipped my mind)
http://www.microsoft.com/express/database/

OLE-DB.NET is universal for accessing other sources, like Oracle, DB2, Microsoft Access and Informix, but it’s a .NET layer on top of OLE layer, so not the fastest thing in the world. ODBC.NET is a deprecated layer provided for backward compatibility to ODBC engines.

More in depth look at Data Providers
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7ee2dwt(VS.71).aspx

Comment: You don't (immediately) need a license for MS-SQL, SQL Express is free for limited personal and commercial use.

Comment: SQLServer.NET data provider can be downloaded for free: the SQL Server instance is licensed not the DB drivers. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=d09c1d60-a13c-4479-9b91-9e8b9d835cdc&displaylang=en

Comment: -1 for not understanding the difference between SQL Server engine and the data providers. A standard XP install will connect to a SQL Server engine with **no** SQL Server specific download or install or license needed

Comment: yes but a sql server is needed somewhere, you can't just connect to a ghost sql server...

Comment: Almost clever.. but how does it relate to the question about Db drivers? The drivers are independent of SQL Server so you can have the drivers but not use them...